# undefined reference to `avcodec_encode_video` when trying to make opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile

[image: opencv output]

I understand it's a ffmpeg error, but I think ffmpeg is deprecated. what should I do with it? i'm new to `make`.

```
root@e0b310d499eb:~/opencv-2.4.9/Release# sudo apt-get install ffmpeg                                                      
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ffmpeg is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ffmpeg' has no installation candidate
```

i tried to install ffmpeg directly from git, but it didn't help.
any suggestions?

Comment: did you run `sudo apt-get update` first?

Comment: try installing `libavcodec-dev` instead